# How to integrate GoogleAdmin SDK APIs and CloudResource APIs in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

Trying to integrate Admin SDK Apis to manage users and assign GCP projects to same users.
Does **spring-cloud-gcp-dependencie**s starter project in spring boot have those ready-made librarries to execute those APIs using service account credentails.?
OR we have to add **google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager** and **google-api-services-admin-director**y dependecies separately in project .